# How to create timestamps automatically for MongoDB Schemas in python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi, pydantic

How can i create timestamps automatically in my schemas in python?

For example in Javascript you can do something like this

`var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: true });`

timestamps: true will create created_at and update_at field in my schema
and it will also update updated_at field every time i change something in that document
How can i achieve this in python

My python schema looks like this

```
class UserSchema(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    user_name: str = Field(...)
    user_email: EmailStr = Field(...)
    
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean with `create timestamps automatically`, but if you mean to add the timestamp at instantiation

```
import datetime
class UserSchema(BaseModel):
    id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias="_id")
    user_name: str = Field(...)
    user_email: EmailStr = Field(...)
    timestamp: datetime.datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
    
    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True
        json_encoders = {ObjectId: str}
```

Here's the link to the official docs, which provides more extensive examples about the different dates and times supported.

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#datetime-types

Comment: yeah but that will be createdAt and there is no updatedAt.
in Javascript when you supply { "timestamp": true } it creates for you automatically
and also updated updatedAt field whenever you update the document automatically.

Comment: Ohhh I see. Well, when you update it via a PUT request, it would change automatically, or?

Comment: but then there is no createdAt? but i think i will have to have a wrapper for update function. Something like updateWithTimestamp i ll let you know if it works

Comment: Best option is to have a basemodel, which then gets inherited by other models with a target method (i.e. GET, POST, PUT)

Comment: Hey @AhmetK, the Pydantic docs suggest using the default_factory Field attribute for the updatedAt behavior: https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#field-with-dynamic-default-value See if that's a fit for what you're looking to do.